# How do I create a view with new snake_case columns (replacing camelCase) and remaining original columns? (using the output of `FORMAT`)

Tags: postgresql

Unfortunately I am in a position where I have to use camelCase column names for my database, as the source data dictates so.

However, I am using an application where I can only query for snake_case columns (as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461486/on-google-data-studio-using-postgresql-data-how-do-i-select-but-for-ca)).

I want to create a view table that has all the same columns, except those with camelCase names replaced with a snake_case name, so this query

```
SELECT * FROM view_name;
```

will return

```
| id  | name | column_one |...|
|-----|------|------------|---|
| ... | ...  | ...        |   |
```

I can do this manually like this:

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT id, name, schema.table."columnOne" AS column_one FROM schema.table
```

but I have too many columns, is there a way to do this automatically for all columns?

UPDATE 1:
Made progress on this, I am able to get the string of all the columns I need from one table like this, but I still don't know how to use it with `CREATE VIEW`:

```
(SELECT FORMAT(
  '%I.%I.%I."%I",',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name !~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'
AND table_name = 'example_table_name')
UNION
(SELECT FORMAT(
  '%I.%I.%I.%I AS %I,',
  table_catalog,
  table_schema,
  table_name,
  column_name,
  lower(
    -- replace all spaces with _, xX and Xx becomes x_x
    regexp_replace(
      -- First, replace spaces with an _
      replace(column_name, ' ', '_'),
      '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
      '\1_\2',
      'g'
    )
  )
)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name ~ ' |[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]'
AND table_name = 'example_table_name')
```

which results in

```
                                    format
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 db.schema.table."id",
 db.schema.table."name",
 db.schema.table."columnOne" AS column_one,
 db.schema.table."columnTwo" AS column_two
```

I want to `CREATE VIEW` from the output of format, how can I do this?

Comment: given that you've got the bulk of your logic down, can you just copy-paste the output? or is there a complication? like - you need to do a bunch of tables-to-views so you have to automate this? if so that may be a separate question.

Comment: @PeterVandivier I could copy-paste it manually but that would take time given the large number of tables. If I could automatically use the output of format in `CREATE VIEW` this would speed things up.

Comment: the current wording implies there's just one table. perhaps you could edit the post to remove questions you've already solved and clarify where you're still blocked

Comment: @PeterVandivier Okay thanks I've edited the wording. I'm still unable to do this for only one table, as I don't know how to use the output of `FORMAT` with `CREATE VIEW`.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the information you need from the information_schema with your favourite scripting language, say Python. The do the formatting in Python and print out the views to a file that you can execute against your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the TL:DR; type, please find the solution [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c008dd2ef2f20756be5a56aef42e15ae&hide=1)

```sql
with snakes as (
    select 
        ordinal_position,
        table_catalog,
        table_schema,
        table_name,
        format('%I.%I.%I',table_schema,table_name,column_name) as full_name,
        lower(
            -- replace all spaces with _, xX and Xx becomes x_x
            regexp_replace(
                -- First, replace spaces with an _
                replace(table_name, ' ', '_'),
                '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
                '\1_\2',
                'g'
            )
        ) as snake_case_table,
        lower(
            -- replace all spaces with _, xX and Xx becomes x_x
            regexp_replace(
                -- First, replace spaces with an _
                replace(column_name, ' ', '_'),
                '([[:lower:]])([[:upper:]])',
                '\1_\2',
                'g'
            )
        ) as snake_case_column
    from information_schema.columns
    where table_catalog =  current_database()
      and table_schema in ('public')
), tables as (
    select 
        format('%I.%I',table_schema,'vw_'||snake_case_table) as view_name,
        string_agg(
                full_name||' as '||snake_case_column, 
                ','||chr(10)||'        ' order by s.ordinal_position

        ) as column_list,
        format('%I.%I',table_schema,table_name) as base_table
    from snakes s
    group by
        s.table_catalog,
        s.table_schema,
        s.table_name,
        s.snake_case_table
)
select 
    'create or replace view '||view_name||' '||chr(10)||
    'as '||chr(10)||
    '    select '||chr(10)||
    '        '||column_list||chr(10)||
    '    from '||base_table||';'||chr(10)||chr(10)
    as create_view_command
from tables;
```

As you can see on the fiddle, the output of this should be one `create view` command for every table in the current database. Please note I haven't worked with postgres [foreign data wrappers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html), so I've removed the cross-database references (but they should be rather trivial to add back in).

The only material additions I've made to your code are the use of `string_agg()` and `group by`. However, re: `format('%I."%I"',...)`, you can lose the double quotes here. As per [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)

> `I` treats the argument value as an SQL identifier, double-quoting it if necessary. ...